# Oracle DB. How to get a running total from multiple columns on one record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that stores a unique ID and 12 monthly values.

I need to provide the front-end a procedure that gives them monthly values in the first row and a running total in the second row for a specific Unique ID. (See table below for desired output).

The first part is easy since its just a simple select statement, the running total is whats tripping me up.

I looked into SUM OVER but that seems to only work if you need a running total on one column. But I have 12 different columns that have data.

What I don't want to do is just a simple Jan22, Jan22+Feb22, Jan22+Feb22+Mar22.

Anyway to go about this? Thanks.

EDIT:
Table Definition

| Unique ID | Jan22 | Feb22 | Mar22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5000 | 1000 | 3000 |
| 2 | 3000 | 2000 | 8000 |

Desired output. The front end team calls the procedure and sends unique ID 1 as parameter.

Below is what I want to display.

| Jan22 | Feb22 | Mar22 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5000 | 1000 | 3000 |
| 5000 | 6000 | 9000 |

Comment: edit the question, show all table definition, and sample data.

Comment: since each column must be named explicitly, i'm not sure you have a choice.

Comment: you must provide a good sample about your monthly data with ID column and how you really expect your data set as output. Otherwise it is difficult to understand the requirement.

Comment: I have added the table definition. The columns go out to December but I only included Jan-Mar in the post.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to provide the front-end a procedure that gives them monthly values in the first row and a running total in the second row for a specific Unique ID.

This is not a database problem; this is a display problem. You should be passing a single row with 12 columns, one for each month, and then if it needs displaying in two rows then the cumulative total should be generated at display time by the front-end and should not be calculated in the database.

---

If you must do it in the database (don't):

> What I don't want to do is just a simple Jan22, Jan22+Feb22, Jan22+Feb22+Mar22.

Unfortunately, that's the way it should be done.

Get all the columns for the unique id and then use `UNION ALL` to get the row again and accumulate the values:

```
SELECT Jan22,
       Feb22,
       Mar22
FROM   table_name
WHERE  unique_id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT Jan22,
       Jan22 + Feb22,
       Jan22 + Feb22 + Mar22
FROM   table_name
WHERE  unique_id = 1
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Unique_ID, Jan22, Feb22, Mar22) AS
SELECT 1, 5000, 1000, 3000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3000, 2000, 8000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | JAN22 | FEB22 | MAR22 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 5000 | 1000 | 3000 |
> | 5000 | 6000 | 9000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c7bab7823e708352ed74615340811cf5)*